# Error in terminal while upgrading scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

[image]

I'm getting this error while upgrading the scikit-learn library

Comment: `pip install wheel`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not an error really, the message just tell you that the version of scikit-learn that you have is up to date if you want to reinstall the package you can easily delete it first by using the command pip uninstall scikit-learn then install it again by using the command pip install scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed `wheel` yet. The latest version is build using `wheel` so install it using

`pip install wheel`

Answer (score 0):

`pip install wheel==0.34.2` should do the trick

https://pypi.org/project/wheel/

[image]